# How to set MS SQL settings like ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI NULL etc with hibernate?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I want to achieve SET ANSI_WARNING OFF equivalent while using hibernate? Is there any hibernate configuration which can do it for me?

Comment: Your title also implies you want to set ANSI_NULLS to OFF. This is highly unrecommended. To quote from [SET ANSI_NULLS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): *"In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature."*. I strongly suggest implementing proper boolean logic over using `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`.

Comment: Apologies for the misleading title. I don't want to set ANSI NULL to off.